# How it's possible to extend function type in kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I just can't understand why it is possible to extend function type in kotlin ? And then why we can't extend `String?` then, which is also a type.

```
interface CustomFunctionType : () -> Unit {
// this is possible, buy how?
}
```

Comment: [`Function<R>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html) is interface and hence open by default. While classes are final by default.

Comment: so you mean that lambda is also a Function as well. Right ?

Comment: A lambda is `Function<ReturnType>` in JVM bytecode, you can try to decompile to Java for a better view. For example `(Int) -> Int` is `Function1<Int, Int>` which is `interface Function<in T, out R>: Function<R> {...}` again inherited from `Function<Int>` so yeah, this is hierarchy.

Comment: String is a final class. Functional declarations are not final. They are like interfaces, which are never final.